# Expected Sequence expression swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using a loop to set the original image for tab bar items so the unselected state isn't gray (my original icons are white). However, it looks like the recent Xcode 8 update broke the code:

```
for (items in 0  ..< tabBar.items!.count ){
    let tabItemIndex = tabBar.items![items]
    tabItemIndex.image = tabItemIndex.image!.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
}
```

}

I'm getting the following errors on the first line: `Expected 'in' after for-each pattern`, `Expected Sequence expression for for-each loop`, and `Expected pattern`.

Can anyone please help me fix this solution? It worked great until today.

Thanks!!

Comment: How about if you delete the parentheses?

Comment: your code has some very strange naming. You call the index `items` and use that to fetch an item, but that you call `index`. why not simply enumerate the items as `for item in items { item.image = …}`?

Comment: @vikingosegundo let's just get him past the syntax error before we try to improve his style!

Comment: @matt using proper enumeration isn't just a style.

Comment: Getting rid of the parenthesis worked! Sorry about the messy style. I actually got this solution from an answer to a question here on StackOverflow

Comment: Okay, glad it worked. I'll give it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`for x in y` is an actual expression in Swift. You cannot break it up with parentheses, `for (x in y)` — that separates the `for` from the `in` and causes the expression to seem like nonsense to the compiler.

So, delete the parentheses and all will be well.

Answer (score 2):

You have some issues on how you're creating your loop, and some very unsafe forced unwrapping. Try this:

```
if let items = tabBar.items {
    for tabBarItem in items {
        if let image = tabBarItem.image {
            tabBarItem.image = image.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
}
```

Or even cleaner, like this:

```
tabBar.items?.forEach { tabBarItem in
    if let image = tabBarItem.image {
        tabBarItem.image = image.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, unlike in Objective-C, there are no parentheses involved in this structure. Remove the parentheses to fix your syntax error.

However, there are style and safety issues here other than the syntax error: see picciano's answer for a much cleaner and safer way to rewrite the loop.

Comment: No no no, @andyvn22, that's _my_ answer.

Comment: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."